# Remote access ssh on Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, remote

I want to enable remote access to my machine. I have thus far enabled port forwarding on router. Lets say the static  local ip address of the machine is 192.xxx.x.x. We will cal the ip address that is visible if I visit [what is my ip](https://whatismyipaddress.com) as 84.xx.xx.xx. In the router settings it is under WAN IP. Lets say the port is 22.

I have than run

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Looking at its status, we see that it is listening.

But here is where I get lost. If I run

```
ssh user@84.xx.xx.xx
```

I get

> ssh: connect to host 84.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused

As I side note, if I try to connect locally,

```
ssh user@192.xxx.x.x
```

everything works fine.

Now, I know that I am making a mistake somewhere. Please tell me where, and help me learn.

#### Edit

Example from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)

> For example, say you wanted to let a friend access your remote desktop, using the command-line SSH client. You would use port number 5900 (the first VNC port), and destination server localhost

```
ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 guest@joes-pc
```

What is joes-pc here? WHich one of the two IPs i listed? How would the command look like in my case? So that it would connect to the right machine? As there are many machines in the network? I thank you for helping me learn.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] or [ubuntu.se] for a personal network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ssh user@84.x.x.x` from a computer on a different network.

It's likely that your router doesn't have "loopback NAT" (or it has it but it's not enabled), which would explain why you can't ssh to your own computer with the router's external address.  Ignore it.

See for example [Wikipedia article on NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I please ask you to look at my edit? This is my first time doing anything like this. Thank you in advance! The command I appended from the example, how would it be translated in my case?

Comment: Don't do anything with tunnels (`ssh -R`) until basic SSH is working.  You need to try `ssh user@84.x.x.x.` from a different network to test it.

Comment: Thank you! So, even though "joes" local IP is 192... the joes ip in the example, is always the router, as that is what is visible to the outside world? And what after I get this working? Could you please parse the command from the example for me? I will accept the answer ether way, as you already answered the original question.

Comment: As well as connecting through to a shell, most ssh clients and servers will create tunnels.  Run `ssh -R 9999:localhost:5900 guest@beta` on computer `alpha` and will try to log in on `beta` in the ordinary ssh way and connect to a shell.  It *also* opens a reverse tunnel: on `beta` it is listening on port 9999, and if something connects to that, it will be connected to port 5900 on `alpha`.  Forward tunnels also available, equally confusing until you're used to them.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Everything is as you said :)